# Drawing a rectangle in canvas from middle of side in both directions

Tags: javascript

I am working on this canvas drawing, and wish to add a new effect of drawing. As you can see the drawing starts from `curPoint` and end at `curPoint` but is there any way to start from `curPoint` and draw from to side to down?

[image]

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasWindow");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var curPoint = {
        x : 300,
        y : 100,
        index : 0   
    }
    var points = [{x:100, y:100}, {x:100, y:300}, {x:500, y:300}, {x:500, y:100}, {x:300, y:100}];
    function toPoints(points){
        var targetPoint = points[curPoint.index];
        var tx = targetPoint.x - curPoint.x,
            ty = targetPoint.y - curPoint.y
        var dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty),
            rad = Math.atan2(ty,tx);
        var velX = (tx/dist)*1;
        var velY = (ty/dist)*1;
        curPoint.x += velX;
        curPoint.y += velY;
        if(dist < 2){
           curPoint.index++;
        }
        c.fillRect(curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 1, 1);
        if(curPoint.index < points.length){
           setTimeout(function(){toPoints(points)}, 5);
        }
    }
    toPoints(points);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasWindow" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just draw two paths at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasWindow");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var curPoint1 = {
    x : 301,
    y : 100,
    index : 0   
};
var curPoint2 = {
    x : 299,
    y : 100,
    index : 0   
};

var points1 = [{x:100, y:100}, {x:100, y:300}, {x:300, y:300}];
var points2 = [{x:500, y:100}, {x:500, y:300}, {x:300, y:300}];

function toPoints(points, curPoint){
    var targetPoint = points[curPoint.index];
    var tx = targetPoint.x - curPoint.x,
        ty = targetPoint.y - curPoint.y
    var dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty);
    var velX = (tx/dist)*1;
    var velY = (ty/dist)*1;
    curPoint.x += velX;
    curPoint.y += velY;
    if(dist <= 1){
       curPoint.index++;
    }
    c.fillRect(curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 1, 1);
    if(curPoint.index < points.length){
       setTimeout(function(){toPoints(points, curPoint)}, 2);
    }
}
toPoints(points1, curPoint1);
toPoints(points2, curPoint2);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasWindow" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```